# Ubuntu 19.04 remote execute windows command?

Tags: command-line, windows

Linux is easy with ssh to execute a command on another system.
But if the other system is Windows not allways ssh is possible.
What is the best way on Ubuntu 19 to solve this problem?
I know winexe or psexec but I dont find a way to use or install it.
And samba don't have the possibility to execute a windows command.
Can an expert give me an answer to this problem?
I say thanks a lot just now.

Comment: This is probably an MS Windows question: what possibility does Windows provide for remote login.

Comment: You can install [ssh server on Windows](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_openssh_server). The latest versions of Windows have a [native/integrated ssh service](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse) that could be enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use **PowerShell** remotely, but it's not the classic cmd.

In Ubuntu 19.04 and above you can install `powershell` with snap.

See [this documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/running-remote-commands) on running remote commands in PowerShell.

Comment: Powershell is available via PPA and is available for all releases according to microsoft (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-linux?view=powershell-6).  I didn't find any in Ubuntu repos (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=powershell)

Comment: Well, Powershell is available on Ubuntu but it does not has the functions for remote access. Have I done anything wrong?

Comment: Some times you need to enable remote access of powershell in your "server". With 'Enable-PsRemoting -Force' you enable in your server the remote.

Comment: The installed version of Powershell don't supply the command Enable-PsRemoting? Against Windows much less  commands are available? Can I fix this?